# How can I add a continuous integration check for Java library compatibility on Android?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have a number of Java libraries that are targeted at being used on both the desktop Java environment and Android Java environment.

I'd like to be able to integrate some sort of Gradle-based lint check in the Java libraries to make sure that I don't use classes/methods unavailable on Android. I've seen that the Android Lint utility can check such things (and output what the minimum Android kit would be to allow it to work).

I know that pulling in the whole Android SDK would work, but it'd be preferable to do it without that on the smaller base libraries that are intended to be shared outside of the Android world.

One reason for this is that I'd like to use Java 8 features that are available through retrolambda but be warned at continuous integration time that I was using an API unavailable in a prior SDK.

Comment: If you are asking for such a library, it is a reason for closing.  If you already have the libraries, and perhaps even can run them manually, but do not know how to add them in your CI cycle, you need to add code showing your current efforts.

Comment: Do not know if there is such a library, searching yields nothing except the Android Lint tool. I cannot find details on how one would use this tool independent of setting up a full Android build environment.

Answer (score 0):

Proguard appears to be able to do an effective job of sanity-checking that all classes referenced are present. It does a bunch of other things that I do not need it to do, however it can be configured to do the following:

- take an input jar/classpath (the newly compiled Java library)
- not require an output jar (no need to save the optimized/obfuscated version)
- take a set of input libraries to resolve references

  - allowing the runtime libraries from Java 7 to be used as a base reference

This allows me to compile using Java 8 features with a reasonable amount of certainty that it should be compatible on Android - either via retrolambda or the new Jack compiler.

Gradle sections to use Proguard for this use:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-base:5.2.1'
    }
}

task proguardCheck(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask, dependsOn: assemble) {
    injars project.jar.archivePath
    libraryjars files(System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME") + "/jre/lib/rt.jar")
    libraryjars files(System.getenv("JAVA7_HOME") + "/jre/lib/jce.jar")
    libraryjars files(configurations.compile)
    // Don't really try to do anything, we just want this tool for it's bytecode lint
    dontshrink
    dontobfuscate
    dontoptimize
    // Don't fail if LambdaMetafactory is missing - it would be handled by Retrolambda / Jack
    dontwarn 'java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory'
}
```

A strong guarantee of compatibility would be to reference the android.jar for the given minimum-compatible version of Android to be targetted. However without pulling in the Andorid SDK, Java 6 is a good target for really old Android and Java 7 for Android SDK >= 4.4 (although NIO 2.0 is missing and probably other APIs as well).